# OAS_VALIDATION_ERROR error with VALIDATION_ERROR in checkout page when paying with Credit card using Paypal woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I using WooCommerce Paypal payment plugins to my wordpress website and want to use the Credit card payment for customer to directly to pay by credit card, but unfortunately it is not working.
There is a paypal option when clicked pay button in checkout, opens popup and within this popup windows, it is possible to pay by credit card or use paypal account to pay.
My problem here is I want this direct pay by credit/debit button to provide way to pay directly, not from paypal's popup. To pay by card directly, I can click that "Debit or Credit Card" button, opens the form to enter card details, then when I click "Pay Now", it says something wrong and takes back to paypal popup. In the browser console, I can see there is an error of "ppxo_inline_guest_unhandled_error" and json.

Here is the screenshot of my setups and errors.

Plugin info
[image]

Checkout page
[image]

After clicking Pay Now button
[image]

There is a post in github issue, it is not exactly same problem and also doesn't tell how to properly solve it. This is the link https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1550

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming error, the card could not be processed. User can 'Try Again' to use non-inline form. If you need more details about why the card could not be processed, contact PayPal.